# error: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, non-well-formed

```
while ($strpos = strpos($text, $search, $offset)) {
        $offset = $strpos + $search_length .'<br>'; 
        $text = substr_replace($text, $replace, $strpos, $search_length);
    }
```

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp..\index.php on line 13

Line 13 is: while ($strpos = strpos($text, $search, $offset)) {

This how I define the variables:

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$search = $_POST['searchfor'];
$offset = 0;
```

Really can not find where caused the error.

The code is doing fine now, cannot explain what exactly happened before. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I would `echo` these variables; then the problem will be obvious

Comment: Well, adding a `'<br>'` to your otherwise numeric `$offset` variable isn't doing you any favours

Comment: @Phil - care to explain where/how the `<br>` is added?

Comment: @Floris Err, line #2 - `$offset = $strpos + $search_length .'<br>';`

Comment: Ah - it happens on the second pass... I was looking at the `offset=0;` and struggling to understand what you were saying. You clearly have identified the solution - namely the place where the numerical `$offset` becomes ill-formed (a string...). Please write as answer so we can all get on with our lives again.

Answer (score 2):

try changing it to:

```
while ($strpos = strpos($text, $search, $offset) !== false) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: @Floris Nope, PHP will evaluate the statement on the left side of the comparison first

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate with `<br>`.  Echo a `br` in the next statement. Error will disappear

```
while($strpos = strpos($text, $search, $offset))  {

    echo $offset= $strpos+$search_length;
    echo '<br>';

        }
```

I don't like echoing a new line but if i use `$search_length`. `br` tag error appear. I do not know why.